# Anywhere Access on 2012 is blank page

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-access, windows-server-essentials

I used to have anywhereaccess on our Windows 2012 R2 Server working perfectly. We share a building with other businesses and the IT system had maintenance, since then I've received this error:

[image]

They're adamant it's nothing they've done but everything I try doesn't seem to work, I've restarted all HTTP services, deleted old SSL certificates and restarted the IIS web services.

When I visit the page, I'm presented with a blank page.

[image]

Lastly, I've also tried looking at what uses port 80 and 443. I used `netstat -b -a` and I got this result:

```
TCP 0.0.0.0:80 PROFILE-SERVER:0 LISTENING
TCP 0.0.0.0:443 PROFILE-SERVER:0 LISTENING
```

I also found it uses PID `4`. Which is the "System"
[image]

Does anyone have any advice or explanation as to why when I login to the remotewebaccess domain it's a blank page?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any public DNS servers such as Open DNS? If so, try changing to googles, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as Open DNS has caused problems with Anywhere access historically.

Also is port 80 and 443 accessible from the outside(Telnet to your external IP to those ports, do it from /outside/ of your network)? Do you have control over the router if you are behind NAT. If so, is the ports 80 and 443 properly forwarded to your internal IP?

If you are not behind NAT and have a public IP. Check all firewalls, if they arent blocking and you dont have access from outside, call your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the SSL handshake failed , You Could Check if the private Key is missing, or broken ...

I suggest using this Diag tool to help you Spot the issue (of course depending on your IIS) Below is For IIS 7:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/09/20/ssl-diagnostics-tool-for-iis-7.aspx

And you can also capture a network trace from the client or server, Filter it to show SSL and TLS , it will clearly show you the process...

Answer (score 1):

The browser errorpage that you posted says it quite clearly - the SSL certificate the box serves is invalid for the domain name you access it with.

The web server seems fine, Anywhere Access is not working because the certificate is invalid.

Have the server set up with a valid certificate containing **all** the domains the server is supposed to be accessed with and it should work.

**Update**:
Try using a different client, a phone or laptop and check if it works there to exclude virus scanners/personal firewalls.
When accessing it, I just get `401 - Not authorized` and a blank response page. It seems like the default error pages were set to blank pages.
 Checking with `nmap -A -p80,443` does look like IIS is running as it should.

Comment: It's now a blank page. So it's not the SSL certificate as now it's a blank page. Check OP

Comment: nmap isn't a valid command and I couldn't find it in the windows dir.

Comment: @BradlySpicer NMAP is a port scanning tool and does not ship with Windows. I don't think it would help you any more if you run it on your box since the server seems to be listening on the appropriate ports.